# phpmyadmin secure installation login without root

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have a secure installation of phpmyadmin on ubuntu 15.10 and apache 2.4. As a result, when I access myserver.com/phpmyadmin, I'm first taken to a dialogue box which asks for a username, password (screenshot attached).

[image]

Now, I've made a read only account of phpmyadmin (Privileges: SELECT, SHOW VIEW, CREATE VIEW) and when the guy enters the credentials of that read account, he's not redirected to the phpmyadmin login page. He then needs to put in the root credentials there to be redirected to that page. On that page however, he's been able to login using his read access credentials.

I've looked into this matter but I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an additional layer of authentication -- probably a `.htaccess` file or similar protection in place. The reason I think this is because you mentioned needing to log in again after the initial popup; phpMyAdmin will only prompt you once and it directly use the MySQL user account, so it's most likely *some* other means of protection is in place.

If you can't find a `.htaccess` file, try looking at/posting your Apache configuration file.